# How to reduce the boot time of the IONIC 2 app?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I have designed the app using IONIC 2. The apk size is 6 MB. The boot time of the app is 11 secs. Could anyone help me how to reduce the boot time?

Ionic version is 2.3.0.
Angular version is 2.4.8

Comment: what command do you use to build your app?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with boot time? Until `device ready` fires? Until a splash screen is hidden? Until some assets have been loaded? It would also be helpful to see some code to get an idea what you're doing once your app launches. 11 secs is way more than normal startup time.

Comment: Have you tried building youre app using the --prod tag?

Comment: Yeah i have tried --prod @JoeriShoeby.

Comment: @Schlaus I am displaying a splash screen in my app. It takes 9 secs to hidden.

Comment: What device are you testing on ?

Answer (score 0):

Build the app using

```
ionic build android --release --prod
```

instead of ionic build android --release

"--prod" flag helped me in my case by reducing boot time from 12-15 secs to 3-5 secs

Comment: Yes. I using --prod for ionic build.

Comment: is it taking 11 secs with --prod flag ??

Comment: Yes @chaitanya.